# For Function answerView why have we taken parameter drawableView as Int?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
private fun answerView(answer:Int , drawableView:Int)
{
    // Function Body
}
 
// Function call is made as Follows
if(question!!.correctAnswer != mSelectedOptionPosition)
{
    answerView(mSelectedOptionPosition,R.drawable.wrong_option_drawable_bg)
}
answerView(question.correctAnswer,R.drawable.correct_option_drawable_bg)

// answerView is any function which highlight wrong or Right answer.
```

I am not Getting the logic why answerView function has its parameter drawableView as Int, although in function call a XML file is passed for it.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in `R` is an `Int` - it's just a generated file that creates named variables for all your resources (that's what the *R* stands for), and assigns each of them an integer value that it refers to internally. That way it can link to the correct resource file using that lookup number.

So you're not passing an actual XML file, just a resource reference that happens to refer to one. In fact there's nothing preventing you from passing *any* kind of resource reference here, or even just a random `Int` that isn't a valid reference at all! You can deal with this by annotating the parameter [with a resource annotation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations#res-annotations) like `@DrawableRes`:

```
private fun answerView(answer:Int, @DrawableRes drawableView:Int) {
    ...
}
```

and that way the linter will warn you if you're not passing a valid drawable reference when you call this function.

Having readable names and separate namespaces like `drawable` and `layout` just makes it easier to work with! Also the generated lookup numbers are **not** stable, no never refer to those directly - always use the `R.thing.whatever` variable and you'll always be using the correct value. The one exception is that an invalid ID will resolve to *-1* - so if you ever see that in your logs, it means you have a bad reference or something's gone missing.

Have a look in the R file itself!